# I Have LUKS Enabled And Integrated With TPM 2. How To Hide Passphrase Screen?

Tags: fedora, luks, plymouth, tpm

**System: Fedora 37, Gnome 43**

I enabled LUKS encryption on setup and enabled auto-decrypt via TPM 2 with following an article from Fedora Magazine. Auto-decrypt works but while it decrypts, it shows the passphrase screen until system boots. How can I hide this screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, after reading up and working out what was asking for the password I tried a sleep for the ask password. I tried a few values 8 seconds the boot screen showed then switched to the password before continuing, 15 didn't show up.

It means that if the TPM decrypt fails the password will eventually show up.

To Hide the Password on startup for 15 seconds (enough time for auto unencrypt) edit systemd-ask-password-plymouth.service in /usr/lib/systemd/system, add:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 15
```

Don't forget to `dracut -f` to rebuild the initramfs and then rebind your disk to the TPM chip depending on what PCR ID's you used.

Comment: Should have been a new line between [Service] and ExecStartPre

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Next time click the question mark on the Answer (and Question) box toolbar. To keep the formatting of outputs, logs, configs, commands... enclose the text in the code brackets `{ }` - see the edited answer for an example. In the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) you'll find more advanced formatting advice.